# Matplotlib colorbar for PatchCollection overrides colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting patches according to values set in the variable values.

```
pc = PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True)  

norm = Normalize()
cmap = plt.get_cmap('Blues')
pc.set_facecolor(cmap(norm(values)))
ax.add_collection(pc)
```

[image]

Now i also want an additional colorbar. If i interject (e.g. before set_facecolor)

```
pc.set_array(values) # values
plt.colorbar(pc)
```

[image]

it works, but now all colors have turned to a greyscale. The following `set_facecolor` does not change anything. Even when i add a `cmap=` command in the `plt.colorbar()` everything remains in the greyscale. I have no clue what to do about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you asking how to color a collection by a specific colormap?

Just set the colormap (`cmap`) as well as the `array`.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

num = 10
data = np.random.random((num, 2))
values = np.random.normal(10, 5, num)

# I'm too lazy to draw irregular polygons, so I'll use circles
circles = [plt.Circle([x, y], 0.1) for (x,y) in data]
col = PatchCollection(circles)

col.set(array=values, cmap='jet')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.add_collection(col)
ax.autoscale()
ax.axis('equal')

fig.colorbar(col)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To explain what's going on in your question:

For collections, the facecolors are either manually set (i.e. `set_facecolors`) or they're colormapped to a range of values (`set_array`) controlled by a colorbar.  These two options are mutually exclusive. Therefore, after you call `set_array`, the original facecolors are ignored.

Comment: Do you know how could I add color with opacity, @Joe? I'm trying to do that, with no success. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966008/individual-color-and-alpha-values-in-path-collection-matplotlib-python Thank you.

Comment: @pceccon - Not sure why your question got downvoted (and then closed). It's a good question.  At any rate, if you use `set_array`, the opacity is either controlled by the colormap or by a single global `alpha` value.  What exactly are you trying to do?  If you'd like the opacity to vary regularly with the color changes, that's possible (you'll need a custom colormap).

Comment: Hi @Joe, after two down votes (not sure why too) and a lot of research, I managed to do it and deleted the question. Thank you for trying to help me. (: